How is principle of least action equivalent to Newtonian mechanics?
I'm confused as to why people call mechanics based on least action equivalent to Newtonian and even more fundamental, whereas least action/Lagrangian mechanics has (as I understood from below - please correct if incorrect) several limitations (e.g. boundary condition) of applicability compared to Newtonian equations of motion.
E.g. that QA (How are Lagrangian mechanics equivalent to Newtonian mechanics?) states in the question: "analytic mechanics (which contain Lagrangian mechanics) and that it contain some equations that are equivalent to Newton's laws but are more fundamental", in the answer Euler-Lagrange equation is compared to Newton's equation of motion.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics:

Lagrangian mechanics is a formulation of classical mechanics founded
on the stationary-action principle (also known as the principle of
least action).
However, the Euler–Lagrange equations can only account for
non-conservative forces if a potential can be found as shown. This may
not always be possible for non-conservative forces, and Lagrange's
equations do not involve any potential, only generalized forces;
therefore they are more general than the Euler–Lagrange equations.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)#Action_(functional)

Given the initial and boundary conditions for the situation, the
"solution" to these empirical equations is one or more functions that
describe the behavior of the system and are called equations of
motion.
Action is a part of an alternative approach to finding such equations
of motion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_principles

Action principles apply to a wide variety of physical problems,
including all of fundamental physics. The only major exceptions are
cases involving friction or when only the initial position and
velocities are given.


Mathematically, they are equivalent because they produce the same equations of motion. I am flagging this to be migrated to physics SE, since you probably want to know how their physical interpretations are the same.

@paulina, thank you. Maybe easier and faster to post in physics and delete here?

Nothing stops you from doing that.

Related Phys.SE question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292710/2451

I would like to know your response to the answer on stackexchange that I linked to in my answer: From F=ma to Hamilton's stationary action It is a recently posted answer to an old question. (The question was posted in 2010. Old questions are hardly ever viewed, so that recent answer is extremely unlikely to receive any votes. That answer has zero votes to it, but that's because it is on a page where it doesn't get views. )

About attribution of 'more fundamental':
As to why such attribution is varied: I offer the following hypothesis:
The Lagrangian formulation is a more abstract form. It would appear that some people rely on the following assumption: the more abstract the representation is, the more fundamental it is.
Example of a case where it works that way:
In celestial mechanics,  when comparing Kepler's laws and Newtonian mechanic plus the inverse square law of gravity: the newtonian representation addresses the physics taking place at a more abstract level.

I am of the opinion that the more-abstract-implies-more-fundamental idea should be viewed with sharp caution. It should definitely not be applied blindly.


As to the newtonian formulation and Lagrangian formulation: the two don't have exactly the same scope, but for the overlapping scope the two formulations are interderivable.
So my starting point is to look at the overlapping scope:
-each of the forces that are involved can be reexpressed as a well defined potential
-any constraints are holonomic

About the interderivability:
What I mean is that within the overlapping scope either can be derived from the other.
A vivid example is the interderivability of Lagrangian mechanics and Hamiltonian mechanics. Those two formulations are transformed to each other by way of Legendre transform. To underline that those two formulations are on equal level: Legendre transformation is its own inverse: applying Legendre transformation twice recovers the original function.
In the case of stationary action and the newtonian formulation the crucial transformation is expressed by the work-energy theorem. In july of this year I posted an answer here on math stackexchange to the question:
How does energy conservation follow from Newton's second law?
In that answer I give the derivation of the work-energy theorem from $F=ma$.
The work-energy theorem motivates the definitions of potential energy and kinetic energy.


There is an answer by me on physics stack exchange where I show it is possible to proceed from $F=ma$ to Hamilton's stationary action in all forward steps. The development is in two stages:

Derivation of the work-energy theorem from $F=ma$
Demonstration that in cases where the work-energy theorem holds good Hamilton's stationary action will hold good also.

From F=ma to Hamilton's stationary action.
(That actual question was submitted in 2010; it was the ninth question to be submitted to physics stackexchange. That question is of course hardly ever viewed anymore, so my recent answer there has little to no chance of receiving any votes. That is to say: that answer has zero votes to it because it doesn't have the chance to get any votes.)



The fact that the scope of the Lagrangian formulation and the scope of the newtonian formulation do not overlap entirely is of minor importance.
The lagrangian formulation is not equipped to handle dissipation of energy, but at the level of atoms and sub-atomic particles that is not a problem: at that level the concept of dissipation of energy is not applicable.
The 'boundary conditions' versus 'initial conditions' issue is only apparently an issue. The demonstation of the interderivability shows why that is only apparently an issue.


About the work of Joseph Louis Lagrange:
When Lagrange formulated the mechanics that he set forth in his work Mécanique Analytique (1789) the available action concept was Maupertuis' action, which is quite distinct from Hamilton's action. Lagrange opted to not use Maupertuis' action as a basis for mechanics. Lagrange offered the assessment that Maupertuis' action is a corollary to the laws of motion, rather than a principle. William Rowan Hamilton's published about theory of motion - including the concept that today we know as Hamilton's stationary action - in 1834.
That is to say: in order to formulate the mechanics presented in Mécanique Analytique it was not necessary for Lagrange to have Hamilton's stationary action. Having the newtonian formulation was sufficient.


A concept that the newtonian formulation and Lagrangian formulation have in common:
The newtonian formulation generalizes to using generalized coordinates. See the following discussion by Richard Fitzpatrick: Generalized forces

To expand on your point about dissipative forces, one could argue that Newtonian mechanics handles it in the crudest, but most practial way possible. Instead of considering the states of all of the particles that recieve kinetic energy from, e.g. an object heating, sliding, or making noise, it just replaces that with some sort of bulk kinematic quantity that breaks the structure of Lagrangian or Hamiltonian mechanics, but yields tractable equations in the Newtonian framework

Your hypothesis on what is more fundamental makes sense, thanks. As for other math I'm not so literate. E.g. what is holonomic? Dict: Exhibiting holonomy. Holomonyper wikipedia "the extent to which". So isholomonicsame asaddictivetoaddition`? Does not seem so, but I have no other hypothesis.

@Martian2020 About the expression 'holonomic constraint'. That relates to whether there is a well defined expression for potential energy. There is a well defined expression for potential energy when the potential difference between point A and point B is independent of how an object moves from pointe A to point B. Gravity has that property. But consider this case: a ball is rolling without slipping over an inclined surface. With different ways to roll from A to B the ball can end up in a different orientation. That is an example of non-holonomic constraint.
